# Menu driven program to first create singly linked list of 'n' no of nodes and then display that created node and further do other operations

Tags: c, singly-linked-list

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<conio.h>
struct node{
   int data;
   struct node *link;
}*head = NULL, *new_node, *ptr=NULL, *prev_ptr, *temp;
```

I want to have a function to create 'n' number of nodes first so that it will make sence to do further operations.

```
 void insertBeg(){
        int info;
        new_node = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        printf("\nEnter data : ");
        scanf("%d",&info);
        new_node->data=info;
        new_node->link=NULL;
            if(head==NULL){
                head=new_node;
            }
            else{
                new_node->link=head;
                head=new_node;
            }
    }

    void insertEnd(){
        int info;
        new_node = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        printf("\nEnter data : ");
        scanf("%d",&info);
        new_node->data=info;
        if(head==NULL){
            head=new_node;
            new_node->link=NULL;
        }
        else{
            prev_ptr=head;
            ptr=head->link;
            while(ptr!=NULL){
                prev_ptr=ptr;
                ptr=ptr->link;
            }
            prev_ptr->link=new_node;
            new_node->link=NULL;
        }
    }

    void displayNode(){
        printf("\nLinked List is : ");
        ptr=head;
        while(ptr!=NULL){
            printf("%d--->",ptr->data);
            ptr=ptr->link;
        }
    }

    void deleteBeg(){
        if(head==NULL){
            printf("\nUnderflow");
        }
        else{
            temp=head;
            head=head->link;
            free(temp);
        }
    }

    void deleteEnd(){
        if(head==NULL){
            printf("\nUnderflow");
        }
        else{
            prev_ptr=head;
            ptr=head->link;
            while(ptr!=NULL){
                prev_ptr=ptr;
                ptr=ptr->link;
            }
            prev_ptr->link=NULL;
            free(ptr);
        }
    }

    void traverse(){
        int count=0;
        ptr=head;
        while(ptr!=NULL){
            ptr=ptr->link;
            count++;
        }
        printf("\nNumber of elements in the list are : %d",count);
    }
```

Also the program would be much user friendly if we could ask the user to create the node first and show him the node created.
Then after ask the user to do any of the operations mentioned below.

```
int main(){
        int choice,ch='y';
        label:
        printf("\nPress 1 to insert at beg\n2 to insert at end");
        printf("\n3 to delete from beg\n4 to delete from end");
        printf("\n5 to display the list\n6 to traverse the linked list : ");
        scanf("%d",&choice);
        switch(choice){
            case 1: insertBeg();
                break;
            case 2: insertEnd();
                break;
            case 3: deleteBeg();
                break;
            case 4: deleteEnd();
                break;
            case 5: displayNode();
                break;
            case 6: traverse();
                break;
            default: printf("\nInvalid Option");
        }
        printf("\nPress y to continue or any other key to exit : ");
        scanf("%s",&ch);
        if(ch=='y' || ch=='Y'){
            goto label;
        }
        getch();
        return 0;
    }
```

Finally display the new list created after the operations done with the list created initially.

Comment: Welcome to SO Ayush pokharel. This seems like a question that could be split into 3 separate questions. As it is it's too broad and reads more like a project scope than a question.

Comment: Myan I just having problem to make it more user friendly. Creating a node at the begining without creating the list just didnt make sence

Comment: I just wanted to make it more user friedly. I am really having trouble with data structure. I have no intentions to waste any ones time. Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I understood from the question and comment section is you wanted to add n number of nodes before proceeding further operation on linked list. My answer based on this assumption.

For this you modify main as below:

```
int main(){
    int choice, ch, n, i;
    printf("Enter the number nodes you want to insert");
    if(scanf("%d", &n) < 1){
        printf("scanf failed while reading n\n");
    }
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++){
        insertBeg();
    }

    label:
        printf("\nPress 1 to insert at beg\n2 to insert at end");
        printf("\n3 to delete from beg\n4 to delete from end");
        printf("\n5 to display the list\n6 to traverse the linked list : ");
        scanf("%d",&choice);
        switch(choice){
            case 1: insertBeg();
                break;
            case 2: insertEnd();
                break;
            case 3: deleteBeg();
                break;
            case 4: deleteEnd();
                break;
            case 5: displayNode();
                break;
            case 6: traverse();
                break;
            default: printf("\nInvalid Option");
        }
        printf("\nPress 1 to continue or any other key to exit : ");
        if(scanf("%d",&ch) < 1){
            printf("scanf failed while taking continue or not option\n");
            exit(1);
        }
        if(ch == 1){
            goto label;
        }
    return 0;
}
```

Note: Correct me if it is not the question you intended to ask.

Comment: If it answers your question you may accept the answer by clicking on the tick mark just below the answer. See this link https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work